# Terminate on instance "std::runtime_error" Hiphop-Php

Tags: c++, runtime-error, hiphop

I have successfully built Hiphop-Php on an ubuntu server 12.04 LTS but when I run the command:

`$HPHP_HOME/src/hphp/hphp test.php`

This error occurs:

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
Aborted (core dumped)`

The same error occured during the `make` command but I used `sudo make` and it dealt with that, but using sudo on the above just removes the `Aborted (core dumped)`. This is happening on a remote server, but I have done the exact same before testing on a VM. I even got root access, as I thought that could help, but it's done nothing.

Just so you know I built with USE_HHVM=0, I need the code unreadable and the bytecode format does this, but the VM I built was as well, I'm just stumped! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but running commands through `sudo` to fix crashes seems like a really bad idea.

Comment: I know but I thought that Hiphop needed greater privileges. It worked! name not valid, made me think of my username not being valid so I tried it since I couldn't find any fixes online for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error comes from GCC's C++ library.  It means something in the program's environment has set a locale for which the locale data files are not installed on the box.  e.g. `LANG=foo_FOO.utf8` where the `foo_FOO` locale data files are not installed.

Try setting `LANG=C` before running it.  Don't use `sudo` to fix crashes. That's not even wrong.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I always miss(don't have a clue about) the little things, thanks again its working now!

Comment: Just for the record, sometimes you can get similar erros if `LC_CTYPE` is set to something not supported on the system. A workaround: `unset LC_CTYPE`

Comment: plus one for the last two sentences!